# How to capture video of Android programmatically without external hardware?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video-capture

I know this question has been asked many times here and many other places but none of the answers provided satisfies my requirement. Basically, I want to be able to perform screen video recording of my app at 30 fps in realtime **without** external hardware, similar to Fraps except it is on Android. My app is a Unity Android app and I have found a plugin (AV Pro Movie Capture) that does exactly what I want but it only works on Windows.

There are others that said it is **not possible** to "Fraps" Android devices directly in real-time with just an installed app or Android SDK functions ([http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/89821-How-do-i-quot-Fraps-quot-my-game-on-iOS-or-Android , 2nd post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/89821-How-do-i-quot-Fraps-quot-my-game-on-iOS-or-Android?p=581249&viewfull=1#post581249)) and instead suggested using external hardware setup such as diverting video signal from Android device to a PC monitor. I had a feeling this is the case because screen video recording is processor intensive and an Android device is obviously not as fast as a PC in its spec.

If the above statement is true, does anyone have any solid technical answers/evidence to it? My boss has been asking for this feature many times and is not convinced when I told him it is very difficult to "Fraps" an Android device due to processor speed; his reason is that "it is as simple as feeding the output video display signals back to camera, how computationally intensive can it be?" I need something more to convince him otherwise.

Update:
I found this free SDK SeeMeGaming by LunarG and it is very close to what I to do on an Android device ( http://www.lunarg.com/see-me-gaming/ ) . Has anyone here used it?

Comment: Your app was built with Unity3D, why don't you run it in editor player and do screen casting there?

Comment: I cannot do that. The end result is that it must be a feature available to the end-users to record currently played scene and allow them to freely access and/or share it, so it has to be on the Android device itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use INDE media pack: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-video-capturing-for-unity3d-applications

Comment: Finally after almost 2 years, someone has developed video capturing capability for Android in Unity. I have yet to try this out but this seems to match exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer to this old question. I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Stack Exchange Answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-capture-video-stream-from-android-phone-screen-and-show-it-on-laptop)

[Using Unity's camera to snapshot the scene](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=TakeScreenshot): Would require that you stitch the png's together using your own code.  No idea how fast this actually runs.

[Another random post with a few other apps](http://androidcommunity.com/samsung-galaxy-s-ii-built-in-screen-capture-no-root-required-20110514/)

The last time I tried to do something similar most posts indicated that I would need a rooted device.  Several apps at the time also required rooted devices, so I gave up on that plan and stuck with dumping Unity's main camera screens to a folder.